# Parsing incomplete Json structure

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON structure that looks like:

```
 {
        "one": "value",
        "two": "value",
        "three": "value"
    }{
        "one": "value",
        "two": "value",
        "three": "value"
    }
```

Basically, it misses square brackets and commas. JSON objects needed to be put into array.
Is there any chance to parse it using javax.json library? It is possible to extract only first JSON object, but what about others?

Comment: So, where did this "JSON" come from?  Why not fix the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either alter the input string to make it valid JSON by adding `[` at the begining, `]` at the end, and replacing `}{` with `},{`, or splitting it after the `}` and parse each object separately and add it to a List.